# Shorter code with For

Tags: php

Is there any way to make this code shorter ?

```
If ($Item_1 != "_") { $items1 = explode("_", $Item_1); } Else {}
If ($Item_2 != "_") { $items2 = explode("_", $Item_2); } Else {}
If ($Item_3 != "_") { $items3 = explode("_", $Item_3); } Else {}
If ($Item_4 != "_") { $items4 = explode("_", $Item_4); } Else {}
If ($Item_5 != "_") { $items5 = explode("_", $Item_5); } Else {}
If ($Item_6 != "_") { $items6 = explode("_", $Item_6); } Else {}
If ($Item_7 != "_") { $items7 = explode("_", $Item_7); } Else {}
If ($Item_8 != "_") { $items8 = explode("_", $Item_8); } Else {}
If ($Item_9 != "_") { $items9 = explode("_", $Item_9); } Else {}
If ($Item_10 != "_") { $items10 = explode("_", $Item_10); } Else {}
If ($Item_11 != "_") { $items11 = explode("_", $Item_11); } Else {}
If ($Item_12 != "_") { $items12 = explode("_", $Item_12); } Else {}
```

I try it make shorter with For but it doesnt work example:

```
  For ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    If (${$Item_ . $i} != "_") .... dont work for me :/
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `If (${"Item_$i"} != "_")`

Comment: A note: You don't need empty `else {}` blocks.

Comment: Although you got answers, consider using arrays so that the code could will be more clear.

Comment: @Voitcus Why not reading the answers? I've mentioned this ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl Maybe you posted your answer when I was typing the comment and have not noticed it. (+1 for you)

Answer (score 4):

The idea is good. You just had a little error while building the variable name. Use the following code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    if (${"Item_$i"} != "_") .... should work 
}
```

What you are doing is called *variable variables* in php. Check  [the manual about that](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for further info and examples.

---

Another idea: Why not using an array? this should suite better here:

```
$item = array (
    'foo', 'bar', 'test', 'xyz', ...
);

for ($i = 1; $i <= count($item); $i++) {
    if ($item[$i] != "_") 
}
```

---

Further note, that you can use the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to shorten the `if` statement. (note that I wouldn't do that in this situation because it is less readable, but I'll at least mention it for completeness):

```
$item[$i] != "_" ? $other[$i] = 'something' : 1; // no else block, just a `NOP 1`;
```

Comment: Nice :) This very helped me :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For clarity try this:

```
$item_var = "Item_".$i;
If ($$item_var != "_"){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using arrays instead if var1, var2, etc. You could easily use a loop too.